# Updating a dictionary inside an array from row selection in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsmutabledictionary, didselectrowatindexpath

I have an array of dictionaries from a JSON feed. This populates a `UITableView`. When the user selects a row I use the `UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark`, and I'm trying to modify the dictionary inside the array for that row, so when the cell is reused again after a scroll it stays correct. However I'm getting an error. Here's my code (shortened for clarity):

**JSON data method:**

```
+ (NSMutableArray *)parseKennelData:(NSString *)type userID:(NSString *)user dogID:(NSString *)dog terms:(NSString *)terms
{
   NSURL *searchURL=[NSURL URLWithString:searchLocation];

   // download and parse the JSON
   NSData *JSONData = [[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:searchURL] autorelease ];

   NSError *error=nil;
   CJSONDeserializer *deserializer = [CJSONDeserializer deserializer];
   NSMutableDictionary *JSONdictionary =[deserializer deserializeAsDictionary:JSONData error:&error]; 

   NSMutableArray *allResults = [JSONdictionary valueForKey:@"kennel"];

   return allResults;
}
```

**View Controller:**

```
interface
{
    NSMutableArray *results;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    //  data for search
    self.results=[JSONData parseKennelData:@"search" userID:@"demo" dogID:@"" terms:self.terms];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSMutableDictionary *rowData = [self.results objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    UITableViewCell *thisCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (thisCell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) 
    {        
        thisCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        thisCell.accessoryView = [[UIImageView alloc]
                          initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tick-button.png"]]; 
        [rowData setObject:@"demo" forKey:@"user_id" ];        
    }
    else
    {
        thisCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;  
        thisCell.accessoryView = [[UIImageView alloc]
                              initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"plusbutton.png"]];
        [rowData setObject:@"" forKey:@"user_id"];
    }

    [self.results replaceObjectAtIndex:[indexPath row] withObject:rowData];
}
```

I'm getting a SIGABRT error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'
```

I thought I'd made sure all my stuff is mutable, so I can't see where it's falling over.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that **deserializeAsDictionary** returns a mutable dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you made sure all your stuff immutable, but just declaring your `*JSONDictionary`,  `*allResults`, and `*rowData` pointers to be mutable doesn't make them mutable. The mutability of those objects depends entirely on the right hand side of the assignment.

From the error you're getting, it's clear that the dictionaries you're trying to edit in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` are immutable. Also, I'm not familiar with TouchJSON but I'm pretty sure `allResults` is immutable too.

To rectify this, you need to make two changes, in both cases using the convenient `mutableCopy` method to make a mutable copy of an immutable array or dictionary. First, make the array returned by `parseKennelData:userID:dogID:terms:` mutable:

```
NSMutableArray *allResults = [[JSONdictionary valueForKey:@"kennel"] mutableCopy];
```

And then, in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`, make a mutable copy of the dictionary before modifying it:

```
NSMutableDictionary *rowData = [[self.results objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] mutableCopy];
```

Comment: You should make a mutableCopy to ensure it is copied to a mutable object, example: NSMutableArray *allResults = [JSONdictionary valueForKey:@"kennel"]mutablCopy];

Comment: That's not enough: if you do that `self.results` will be a mutable array of immutable dictionaries.

Comment: I saw that, I was just showing how to easily make a mutable copy of an immutable object as an example. I don't use TouchJSON so I can't really say how the data comes back. I should have made that more clear. By the way iOS5 has a new JSON API, which makes this stuff a lot easier. Thank God, it's been long overdue. Thanks for the clarification, I don't want to confuse anyone, thats the opposite of what SO is all about.

Comment: It's all good: while reading the original question again to make sure whether the dictionaries were immutable too, I figured out the complete solution. :)

Comment: Much appreciated guys - I'd heard of mutablecopy but wasn't thinking of it in that way.  I'm used to C# and just casting to a format.